# why is no exception generated in android

Tags: android

I have this code which generates no error or exception and at the same time it just doesn't work. Simply does nothing and sits there. I am not able to understand why or if any error even occurs.

```
//Method to post data to webservice

public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Creating new user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.rgbpallete.in/led/api/signup").openConnection());
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        urlConnection.connect();
        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200){
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
            String message = json.getString("message");
            boolean error = json.getBoolean("error");

            error(error, message);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This code does nothing when executed through my device, and on debugging I have found out that it dies on the line `OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();`

Why is it not generating any exception even though it is inside a try catch block and if there has been no exception or error then why does it not work?

Comment: did you provide permission for accessing INTERNET in your manifest

Comment: close your logCat and open again.

Comment: Yes I have given permission

Comment: remove that `throws UnsupportedEncodingException` in method declaration

Comment: I think I might be doing network operations in the main thread, would that be the cause? @eriuzo

Comment: @RickRoy did the toast appear? when is this method called? you may be right, but that usually throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: Yes the toast did show. The method is called when user clicks on signup button to register a new account. I am looking into asyntasks to see if it would solve the issue but I am very new have no idea how to impliment asyntasks @eriuzo

Comment: @RickRoy yes please do. if that solves the issue, then the logcat not showing anything is a separate issue..